# jquery toggle div based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button group on a survey form whose html looks like:

```
<label>Would you like to compete?</label>
      <input type="radio"  name="compete" value="2" id="competenoradio" >
      <label for="compete_no">No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="compete" value="1" id="competeyesradio">
      <label for="compete_yes">Yes</label>
      <div id="competeyes">
        <label class="competeyestxt" hidden=true>Which Location?</label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" maxlength="2000" name="competeyestextarea" class="competeyestxt" hidden="true">
        </textarea>
      </div>

The div at the bottom with id 'competeyes' need to be toggled between invisible to visible
 based on whether the user selected radio button with id 'compete_yes'.
```

Here is my attempt at it, which does not work.

```
Attempt 1:
$('#competeyesradio').bind('change',function(){
  $('#competeyes').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});


Attempt 2:

$('div.input input:radio').bind('change',function(){
   $('#competeyes').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});

Attempt 3:

$('[name=compete]').bind('change',function(){
  $('#competeyes').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
 });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are using `$(this).is(':checked')` to check if the current element is checked. It will always be true.

```
$('input[name="compete"]').bind('change',function(){
    var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
    $('#competeyes').toggle(showOrHide);
 });
```

Your second problem was that you were using `hidden="true"` for the fields. You should use CSS to hide the fields. Here is the HTML markup you should be using:

```
<label>Would you like to compete?</label>

<input type="radio"  name="compete" value="2" id="competenoradio" >
<label for="compete_no">No</label>

<input type="radio" name="compete" value="1" id="competeyesradio">
<label for="compete_yes">Yes</label>

<div id="competeyes" style="display:none">
    <label class="competeyestxt">Which Location?</label>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="40" maxlength="2000" name="competeyestextarea" class="competeyestxt"></textarea>
</div>
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/N8pCq/)

Comment: @Qtax: That will do the trick, but I didn't want the OP to be surprised by the code.

Comment: What is $(this) in the current case? I assumed that in the statement  $('#competeyes').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));});  $(this) would be #competeyes. No?

Comment: @truthSeekr: `$(this)` will refer to the checked radio button, if `No` is chosen, the value will be 2. However, if yes is chosen, the value will be `1`, which is exactly what we look for with `($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[id=competeyesradio]:checked')(function(){ $('#competeyes').toggle();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like what is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9CfUB/1/)

```
$('input:radio').bind('change',function(){
    $('#competeyes').toggle($(this).attr('id') == 'competeyesradio');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#competenoradio[checked]")( 
    function() { 
      $('#competeyes').toggle();
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you validating it when toggle just works? At most, it provides you a call back. You should try this:

`$('#competeyes').toggle();`

Answer (score -3):

You can try [this one](http://codecanyon.net/item/selective-enabledisable-form-elements-with-jquery/155578), although not a free solution.

Disclosure: I'm the developer.

Comment: Rubbish answer! One, you're just trying to fish for customers. Two, the user wants to TOGGLE elements based on checked radio buttons, not disable/enable like you have provided. Three, why on earth do you want to BUY a plugin for something that only needs a couple of lines of easy code?!! Four, if this link ever becomes inactive, this answer becomes useless.